# XCOPY Command Date option for copying files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Can someone tell me if there is any way if we don't want to copy the files after the specified date.
E.g. if i specify the date 10-MAY-2017 & 11-MAY-2017 and folder has files for 10 & 11 May 2017. So if want only the 10-MAY-2017 files to copied. is there is any way ?

Comment: Read the documentation (type `xcopy /?` into command prompt), then you will find out! Consider to switch to [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)...

Comment: If you insist in using `xcopy`, you could do the following: `xcopy /L /D:... "source" "destination" > "tempfile.txt"` (list files changed on or after date), then `xcopy /L "source" "destination" | findstr /V /X /L /G:"tempfile.txt" > "copylist.txt"` (list files changed before date), then `xcopy /T "source" "destination"` (prepare directories), then copy all files from file `copylist.txt` in a loop (see [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html))...

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Can someone provide the solution

Comment: Then you likely did something wrong. As I said, switch to `robocopy`, then it is quite easy...

Answer (score 2):

For the task at hand, [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) is the easiest way to do it:

```cmd
robocopy D:\Source D:\Destination *.* /S /MINAGE:20170511
```

Despite the name of switch `/MINAGE`, not the creation but the last modification date is regarded.

Note that I specified the date of the next day, because files of the given date are already excluded.

To copy only files from 10-May-2017, the command line has to be like this:

```cmd
robocopy D:\Source D:\Destination *.* /S /MINAGE:20170511 /MAXAGE:20170510
```

because the `/MAXAGE` option of `robocopy` still includes the given date, in contrast to `/MINAGE`.

---

In case you insist on using `xcopy`, here is a script based on `xcopy` that does the following steps:

- create a list of files that must not be copied, because they are modified on the given date or later; for this `xcopy /L /F /D:` is used: `/L` means to list but not copy, `/F` defines to output fully resolved source and destination paths, and `/D:` lets define a last modification date;
- filter out all the files above from a list of all available files (`xcopy /L /F`) using `findstr`;
- copy the plain directory tree (`xcopy /T`);
- walk through the filtered file list and copy every single file individually by `copy`;

This is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "SOURCE=D:\Source"      & rem // (source directory)
set "DESTIN=D:\Destination" & rem // (target directory)
set "PATTERN=*.*"           & rem // (file pattern)
set "COPYDATE=05-11-2017"   & rem /* (last modification date; only files are copied
                              rem     which are modified earlier; check format!) */
set "TEMPFILE=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (list of source files not to copy)
set "COPYLIST=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.lst" & rem // (full list of files to copy)

rem // List files modified on or after given date:
> "%TEMPFILE%" (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=>" %%F in ('
        xcopy /L /I /F /D:%COPYDATE% "%SOURCE%\%PATTERN%" "%DESTIN%" ^| find ":"
    ') do (
        set "FILE=%%F"
        rem /* Double every `\` as `findstr` uses such as escape character;
        rem    then append ` -> ` which is used by `xcopy /F` as separator: */
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        (echo(!FILE:\=\\!^> )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem /* List files modified before given date
rem    (actually the temporary `%COPYLIST%` file is not really necessary,
rem     but it is quite convenient for understanding what is going on; instead
rem     the below `for /F` loop could parse the output of this command line): */
xcopy /L /I /F "%SOURCE%\%PATTERN%" "%DESTIN%" | find ":" ^
    | findstr /V /B /L /I /G:"%TEMPFILE%" > "%COPYLIST%"
rem // Prepare directory tree as `copy` (below) cannot create directories:
xcopy /I /T "%SOURCE%\%PATTERN%" "%DESTIN%" > nul
rem // Copy files from list:
for /F "usebackq tokens=1* delims=>" %%E in ("%COPYLIST%") do (
    set "LEFT=%%E" & set "RIGHT=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ECHO copy /Y "!LEFT:~,-2!" "!RIGHT:~1!"
    endlocal
)
rem // Clean up temporary files:
del "%TEMPFILE%" "%COPYLIST%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Comment: Thanks for RobCopy command but if there are files 9,10 & 11. And I want to copy for only 10th date and this robocopy command copies 9 & 10 both.

Comment: You mean you want to copy only files from a certain date? This is not qhat your question says...

Comment: does adding maxage switch help you sandwich to the one day you are trying to copy? `robocopy D:\Source D:\Destination *.* /S /MINAGE:20170510 /MAXAGE:20170510`

Comment: @gordon, I think you have to use `/MINAGE:20170511`, because files with the given date or newer are already excluded, together with `/MAXAGE:20170510`, because files with that date or newer are included...

Answer (score 1):

/D:mm-dd-yyyy Copy files changed on or after the specified date. If no date is given, copy only files whose source date/time is newer than the destination time.

Example: xcopy   /D:mm-dd-yyy