# Xcopy should copy all files older then a specific date

Tags: date, batch-file, xcopy

I am working first time with xcopy and I have to copy all files that are older then a specific date.

The parameter /d copys all newer files then the specific date. 
Is there any way to copy older files?

And it has to be with xcopy, robocopy is not an option.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate: [XCOPY Command Date option for copying files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44235682)

Comment: Consider to switch to [`robocopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) and use its `/MINAGE` option...

Comment: The only way you will be able to do it with xcopy is to get file attributes do a few checks and loops, chuck the newer files aside and only copy the older files. Default xcopy has a /D date function, but that is to copy files newer than that date.

Comment: The OP stated that **robocopy is not an option**. This is therefore not a duplicate of the question mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `xcopy` command unfortunately does not have an option for selecting files *older* than a certain date, so, also unfortunatly, `robocopy` is the only option.

The `robocopy` command offers a `/minage:MM-DD-YYYY` parameter (that's what i'm calling it anyway) that selects files with a minimum age of MM-DD-YYYY.

Your syntax should look something like this:

```
ROBOCOPY Source_folder Destination_folder /minage:MM-DD-YYYY [options]
```

Here is more information if it is needed:

https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to ivyomni's answer of combining forfiles and xcopy, I did this:

```
set startDate=10-4-2021

for /d %%i in (*.*) do (

   pushd %%i

   Echo now in %%i

   Rem: The following is sort of a cheat. The forfiles sets the maxdate and the xcopy sets the min date

   echo on

   forfiles /M *.zip /D -10/09/2021 /C "cmd /c xcopy @file C:\ZipFilesForLogAnalysis_Temp /D:%startDate% "

   echo off   

   popd   

  )
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with a forfiles infront of the the xcopy. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: Please revisit this, whilst your statement may be true, it is not useful to future visitors as is. Please [edit] to include the code that you've used to achieve the intended goal, or self-delete the answer to prevent future down-voting.